# Regex to match either range or list of numbers

Tags: regex

I need a regex to match lists of numbers and another one to match ranges of numbers (expressions shall never fail in both cases). Ranges shall consist of a number, a dash, and another number (N-N), while lists shall consist of numbers separated by a comma (N,N,N). Here below are some examples.

**Ranges:**

```
'1-10' => OK
Whateverelse => NOK (e.g. '1-10 11-20')
```

**List:**

```
'1,2,3' => OK
Whateverelse => NOK
```

And here are my two regular expressions:

1. [0-9]+[\-][0-9]+
2. ([0-9]+,?)+

... but I have a few problems with them... for example:

When evaluating `'1-10'`, ***regex 2*** matches `1`... but it shouldn't match anything because the string does not contain a list.

Then, when evaluating `'1-10 11-14'`, ***regex 1*** matches `1-10`... but it shouldn't match anything because the string contains more than just a range.

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Is `1,2,4` OK? Do you need the numbers to be in sequence?

Comment: just as a tip, you can use this: http://regexpal.com/ to test regex

Comment: When you want advanced features it also depends on who's flavor of regex's you are using. Perl has one set of features. Awk another. UNIX style programs deeply depend on the OS being used.

Comment: **Regular expressions are for matching patterns, not checking numeric values.** Find a likely string with the regex, then check its numeric value in whatever your host language is (PHP, whatever).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
^((\d+-(\*|\d+))|((\*|\d+)-\d+)|((\d)(,\d)+))$
```

Test results:

```
1-10         OK
1,2,3        OK
1-*          OK
*-10         OK
1,2,3 1-10   NOK
1,2,3 2,3,4  NOK
*-*          NOK
```

Visualization of the regex:

[image: Visualization of the regex]

Edit: Added for wildcard `*` as per OP's comment.

Comment: This works and is exactly what I'm looking for... I just added support for wildcards to allow expressions like '3-\*' or '\*-10': ^(([\\*\d]+-[\\*\d]+)|((\d)(,\d)+))$; the problem is that this regex matches also expressions like '\*-\*' (the wildcard can be either on the right or on left, not on both sides).

Comment: I am assuming that you want to also match `1-*, *-1` but not `*-*`? See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

This one is a little different.  It's for ports on a Procurve switch.
`^(((\d+)|(\d+-\d+))(,((\d+)|(\d+-\d+)))*)$`
It's in perl.

```
1                    OK
2                    OK
3                    OK
1-4                  OK
0-A                  NOK
83-91                OK
14,15,16             OK
14,20-25,91          OK
a,b-c,5,5,5          NOK
this-is,5,7,9        NOK
9,8,1-2,1-7          OK
```

I didn't include the `*` from above.  And what did you (@unlimit) use for that wonderful diagram?

-E

Comment: I think to move (\d+-\d+) before (\d+) to have a pattern correct with your test result:
(((\d+-\d+)|(\d+))(,((\d+-\d+)|(\d+)))*)

Comment: I just tested it (again), and it works as it should.  That is, it returns the results listed in the response.  What would moving the expression around change?

Comment: I tested your regex at https://regexr.com and it doesn't match all of the test examples.

Comment: Does is work with perl?  Unless I made a cut-and-paste-o, those are results from a real test.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should use [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) to make sure that the regex match encompasses the entire string and not just a substring:

```
^[0-9]+-[0-9]+$
```

Then, the comma is optional in your second regex. Try this instead:

```
^([0-9]+,)+[0-9]+$
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution to your issue is to wrap an extra set of brackets around the second result:

```
(([0-9]+,?)+)
```

As others have noted if you are taking text input and thats the whole input you should start and finish it with `^` and `$`:

```
^(([0-9]+,?)+)$
```

If you are searching a body of text to extract these values then you wouldn't need that.

The brackets mean a match group. Its also possible to mark the inner bracket as "non-capturing group" if you add `(?:` to the start instead of `(`. This would leave you with:

```
((?:[0-9]+,?)+)
```

Which would mean the only captured value is the one you wanted. You could also just ignore the second capture.

Answer (score 0):

I needed something to match a list of integers that are comma separated, such as `1,2,3,4` but also specify ranges such as `100-255` and combinations thereof, such as `1011,1100-1300,1111,1919-9999,2111`. Basically the OP request and combinations of it.

For this, I use the following regular expression tested over at Regex101.com:

`^\d+((\,|-)\d+)*$`

You can think of this as:

1. From the start of the string
2. Expect 1 or more digits, and either...
3. A literal comma and 1 or more digits, or...
4. A hyphen and 1 or more digits
5. with (3) and (4) repeating zero or more times
6. Until the string end

This permits all the following to be valid:

```
2011,2100-2300
2011,2013
1014-2024
999
1011,1100-1300,1111,1919-9999,2111
```

Note: global and multiline regex options `/gm` should be included if being used for multiline input

The downside is something like `100-100-100` is still valid, even though other types of change will ensure no match. Not sure of the complexity to resolve it further, but it was good enough for my needs.